# Ellipsize not working in ConstraintLayout, the TextView overlap other view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm doing a simple layout:

[image]

To do that I have written the followed layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/price_bottom_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.81" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/icon_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.37777779" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/icon_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@color/yellowError"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="#FFA0A0A0"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="3"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="12sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/price_bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.48"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_icon"
        tools:text="TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST test test" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_price_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="#26525A6B"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="#FF5b6b8d"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/price_bottom_guideline"
        tools:text="1000€"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/price_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="item_price_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/price_bottom_barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="item_price_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But there is a little tedious issue.. There isn't space for the third row but the ellipsize not appears.

For instance if I will set the constraint layout height to 110 dp, I obtain this result:

[image]

The text in the item_label TextView doen't resize and moreover the ellipsize doesn't works.
The text goes under the bottom price. I don't understand why.

I'm tring to create a dinamic layout, but it is not so easy ..

I've tried:

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: android:maxLines="3" It's working as you code it

Comment: No it's not working. 
The result is the first image, and it's not what I want. There isn't space for the third row but the ellipsize doesn't appears

Comment: @javdromero I have edited the question with more detail :) Thanks for the answer !